# snake in javascript - cant access a property in method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to implement a basic snake game in js/jquery. And here is what I have so far:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    Game = {
        Snake: function(startingLength) {
            this.snakeComponents = [], this.direction = 'right', this.length = startingLength;

            growSnake = function() {
                this.length += 1;
            }
        },

        gameSnake: {},

        gameSpeed: 0,

        init: function(startingSnakeLength, gameSpeedParam) {


            $.extend(this.gameSnake, new Game.Snake(startingSnakeLength));
            this.gameSpeed = gameSpeedParam;

            for (var i = 0; i < startingSnakeLength; i++) {
                this.gameSnake.snakeComponents.push({
                    x: i,
                    y: 0
                });
            }
            setInterval(Game.update, this.gameSpeed);
        },

        update: function() {
            dx = {
                right: 1,
                left: -1,
                up: 0,
                down: 0
            };
            dy = {
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
                up: 1,
                down: -1
            };

            var snakeLength = this.gameSnake.snakeComponents.length;
            var newSnakeHeadX = this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[snakeLength - 1].x + dx[this.gameSnake.direction];
            var newSnakeHeadY = this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[snakeLength - 1].y + dy[this.gameSnake.direction];

            //update snake components
            this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[snakeLength - 1].x = newSnakeHeadX;
            this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[snakeLength - 1].y = newSnakeHeadY;

            for (var i = 0; i < snakeLength - 1; i++) {
                this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[i].x = this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[i + 1].x;
                this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[i].y = this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[i + 1].y;
            }

            Game.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.gameSnake.length; i++) {
                console.log('Snake position: (' + this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[0].x + ',' + this.gameSnake.snakeComponents[0].y + '), ' + '(' + gameSnake.snakeComponents[1].x + ',' + gameSnake.snakeComponents[1].y + '), (' + gameSnake.snakeComponents[1].x + ',' + gameSnake.snakeComponents[1].y + ')')
            };
        }

    };


    Game.init(3, 1000);


});
```

Now, I can access the Snake instance (this.gameSnake) in the init method, but it becomes undefined when the code is on the update method. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: sorry for that..im new here and my code is actually properly indented in the text editor that im using (notepad++) but i can't seem to "exactly copy-and-paste" my source code in the acual stack overflow post

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the age old problem of an incorrect execution context when using setInterval. Change the code in `render` to:

```
    render: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < Game.gameSnake.length; i++) {
            console.log('Snake position: (' + Game.gameSnake.snakeComponents[0].x + ',' + Game.gameSnake.snakeComponents[0].y + '), ' + '(' + Game.gameSnake.snakeComponents[1].x + ',' + Game.gameSnake.snakeComponents[1].y + '), (' + Game.gameSnake.snakeComponents[1].x + ',' + Game.gameSnake.snakeComponents[1].y + ')')
        };
    }
```

The reason `this` doesn't work is that you aren't calling the function like this: `Game.update();`.

What you are instead doing is passing the function as an argument to `setInterval`, which executes it in the global scope (meaning that when `update` runs, `this` is the window object). Since `this` doesn't refer to `Game` anymore, we are instead deciding to refer to `Game` explicitly.

There's plenty of good tutorials out there for JS scope, you might want to have a look at them. Good luck!

Comment: +1 , following your solution, I think it is also needed to replace all `this` for `Game` in the `update:` function so the fiddle works.

Comment: @Nelson The question originally had the `render` method in the `setInterval`, he has since changed it to `update`, so yes in that case `update` is the one where you need to avoid use of `this`.

Comment: Thanks..I think it fixed the problem, but could you provide the reason why Game.gameSnake works while this.gameSnake does not..Based from my understanding of javascript (I am a newbie though) the latter's supposed to work.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! Thanks, hopefully i become a better js programmer :))